# I can find a Control by name, but how do I find an OvalShape by name

Tags: c#

I am trying to select something which is not a Control - An OvalShape.

This works to find a button

```
string y = "btn_down_" + x;
Button button = this.Controls.Find(y, true)[0] as Button;
```

How can I do the same thing to find an OvalShape for example: (this doesn't work obviously)

```
string y = "ovalShape_" + x;
OvalShape light = this.Controls.Find(y, true)[0] as OvalShape;
```

[image]

_____Solution_____

```
string z = "ovalShape" + (21-x);
OvalShape light = shapeContainer2.Shapes.OfType<OvalShape>().FirstOrDefault(ov =>    ov.Name == z);
```

---

Comment: It all depends on what your oval shape IS? Could you please include its definition? Also, how have you added `OvalShape` into your form?

Comment: Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.OvalShape yes its added to the form

Comment: If its not possible I might have to just use labels and change the background of those instead. However this will involve naming a whole bunch of OvalShape.. nooo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some links provided in @gideon's answer, you can try it this way :

Get the default ShapeContainer first, then search through shapes inside the container having type `OvalShape` and name equals `y`.

```
string y = "ovalShape_" + x;
var shapeContainer = this.Controls.OfType<ShapeContainer>().FirstOrDefault();
OvalShape light = shapeContainer.Shapes.OfType<OvalShape>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == y);
```

This code worked fine for me, but name generated after dragging `OvalShape` on to Form is something like `"ovalShape" + x` instead of `"ovalShape_" + x` here.

Comment: Thank! I found the ovalshapes inside shapeContainer2

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.ovalshape.aspx) I see that a Shape is added first on a [ShapeContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shapecontainer.aspx) which is just a container control.

The ShapeContainer then has a property called [Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shapecontainer.shapes.aspx) which is of type [ShapeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shapecollection.aspx) and exposes list methods like [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shapecollection.contains.aspx).

Assuming you have set it all up like this:

```
 Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer canvas = 
    new Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer();
 Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.OvalShape oval1 = 
    new Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.OvalShape();
 // Set the form as the parent of the ShapeContainer.
 canvas.Parent = this;

for(int i =0;i < canvas.Count; i++)
{
  var shape = (Shape)canvas.Item[i];
   //now check if shape is your oval by looking at it's properties.
}

//You could also do this:
// (But this means you have to store a reference to your shape somewhere
// as some sort of global, not very good design.)
OvalShape myShape = ..
int index = canvas.IndexOf(myShape);
canvas.Item[index];//returns your shape.
```

If you are going with the for loop approach, you could check for the shape's Name property. You could also use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shape.tag.aspx) property; Set the tag to say `"OvalShape"` and then check for this in your loop : `if(shape.Tag == "OvalShape") {..`.

Comment: I dragged the OvalShapes onto the form from the toolbox

Comment: @TomS ok. My best guess is that you should have a control called `shapeContainer1`, which is accessible in your form. This variable is what I call `canvas` in my code.