# concatenate Rectangle control name for shape in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, powerpacks

This is in WinForms. and i am using `microsoft.vsualbasic.powerpacks`
how can i concatenate Rectangle control name in c# this is what i have so far

```
  string n = "1";
  Rectangle match = this.Controls.Find("rectangleShape" + n,true)[0] as Rectangle;
  match.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!  - Winforms: Are you trying to cast a Control to Rectangle?? That will not work. Nor do Rectangles have colors of any kind..

Comment: i am targetung Winforms

Comment: when i target a rectangles name directly it does have back color.

Comment: Do look up [Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Did you create a Rectangle class of your own? - Also: What is the question? Wht happens??

Comment: hmmm i used `microsoft.vsualbasic.powerpacks` this

Comment: Well, this is info you need to add to the question and also as a tag..

Comment: Try some of the [solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507354/i-can-find-a-control-by-name-but-how-do-i-find-an-ovalshape-by-name)...

Comment: okay will do try

Comment: it didnt really help :(

Answer (score 0):

> Try some of the [solutions
>   here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507354/i-can-find-a-control-by-name-but-how-do-i-find-an-ovalshape-by-name)... – Idle_Mind
>
> okay will do try – droid fiji
>
> it didnt really help :( – droid fiji

Here's a working example based on the solution I linked to in the comments.  Note that the **BackStyle** property of your RectangleShape needs to be Opaque for you to see the color you set!

This code will set the BackColor of rectangeShape1 thru rectangeShape3 to Red:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string rectName;
            string rectBaseName = "rectangleShape";
            var shapeContainer = this.Controls.OfType<ShapeContainer>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (shapeContainer != null)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    rectName = rectBaseName + i.ToString();
                    RectangleShape match = shapeContainer.Shapes.OfType<RectangleShape>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == rectName);
                    if (match != null)
                    {
                        match.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        match.BackStyle = BackStyle.Opaque;
                    }
                }
            }      
        }

    }

}
```